# Angular routing optional parameter validation

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have routing in my application where first parameter is not dedicated. It depends on which languages my application have

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':lang',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './modules/home/home.module#HomeModule',
      },
          {
        path: 'offers',
        loadChildren: './modules/offers/offers.module#OffersModule',
      },
      {
        path: 'blog',
        loadChildren: './modules/blog/blog.module#BlogModule',
      },
    ]
 }
]
```

Can I do validation here where if user will enter incorrect url it will redirect to 404 page?

For example `domain.com/en/blog` is valid url but `domain.com/anotherurl` not.

I'm using version 7 of angular

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. What you can do is use a resolver:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':lang',
    component: MainComponent,
    resolve: {foo: LanguageResolverService}
    children: []
```

The resolver would look something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class LanguageResolverService implements Resolve<null> {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, router) {

        const language = route.paramMap.get('lang');

        if(allowedLanguages.includes(language)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['404']);
        }           
    }
}
```

Now, if your language exists, the resolver will simply continue to the desired route. If it does not, you can redirect the user to any page you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wildcard for this. If you place this after all of your language paths. The router will match starting from the top and this will be used if nothing else is matched.

```
  {
        path: "**",
        redirectTo: "404",
    },
```

Comment: This will not work. First parameter is optional so any url is matched

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
{
path: '**', // Wildcard
component: PageNotFoundComponent
}
```

PageNotFoundComponent can be your custom error handler

Comment: This will not work. First parameter is optional so any url is matched

Comment: That's why you add it at the bottom of your path hierarchy as a last resort kind of thing.

Comment: In my case not. On some urls second parameter is also optional.. Thanks anyway I think resolver way is it what I need